# Should I implement actions inside the methods of an InputListener object?

Tags: java, slick2d

I am making a button using `MouseOverArea`. After some trial and error, I realized I can override the methods in `InputListener` to do particular actions when an input event is notified.

For example, do things when mouse left button is pressed while cursor is over the component.

```
@Override
public void mousePressed(int button, int mx, int my) {
    if (isMouseOver() && button == Input.MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON) {
        // Some magic happens
    }
}
```

However, I will not able to do things like changing current game state because no Game object around. I know there are many ways to solve this problem, but I would like to know what is the Slick way to do this.

Are these methods suitable for such behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

One way to modify game states is to use boolean states; Which are boolean variables that hold the state of the game or player. For example:

```
boolean isMovingUp, isMovingLeft, isMovingRight, isMovingDown;
```

You can then set these to true/false depending on what mouse or keyboard event takes place and your game class then read these variables, like so:

```
if (isMovingUp) {
  // do something
  isMovingUp = !isMovingUp;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. However, implement such logic inside the methods means these flags will only be updated after certain input events fired. What if I want a action executed only once ? I can reset the flag after the action is finished, but it seems weird for me to do such things outside the component itself.